# The simplest analytic subvariety in $\mathbb{CP}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In complex geometry, the famous Chow's theorem states: every compact analytic subvariety in complex projective space $\mathbb {CP}^n$ is an algebraic variety. This seems like a miracle to me, and I want to have the simplest example to help me understand it. In order to understand it better, I first start from the affine space case, and I think the simplest and non-trivial example of analytic subvariety in affine space $\mathbb C^2$ is $y=e^x$, which is obviouly non-algebraic, and I wonder why when it comes to projective case, it becomes algebraic, so my question is:

Is there an analog of $y=e^x$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$? if not, what's the simplest non-trivial analytic subvariety in $\mathbb{CP}^2$? I just wanna have an example as easy as possibel to persuade me that the any analytic subvariety in projective space is indeed algebraic. Does anyone have consider the similar problem before?

Comment: How about considering a line?

Comment: @Nissokam, it is easy to construct a algebraic variety in $\mathbb P^n$, but what I need is how can we prove arbitrary analytic subvariety is algebraic, this is the main point.

Comment: In the case of $\mathbb{P}^2$ it is easy, if you take a curve, then it is given by the analytic section of a holomorphic line bundle, but such bundles are classified and are of the form $\mathcal{O}(d)$ whose analytic sections are algebraic. If you take a sub variety of dimension 0, then it is even more obvious.

Comment: @Nissokam, 'such bundles are classified and are of the form $\mathcal O(d)$' actually your argument involves some deep theory, for example Hodge theory? which make a simple phenomenen more complicated, can we give a naive expaination of why analytic is algebraic?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Do you want a proof of Chow's theorem in the special case of the plane? That is that all analyitc (compact) subvarities of $\mathbb{P}^2$ are actually algebraic? I don't know any totally elementary proof of that, I mean not more elementary than the general case or that the one previously mentionned. 
Or do you want to know why you cannot prolong $y=e^x$ as a compact analytic subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^2$ for this, just look at the equation in the "other" affine open subset, you will see that the equation $u=ve^{1/v}$ cannot be prolonged for $v=0$.

Comment: @Nissokam, can you say something detailed on why $y=e^x$ in the other affine open subset is $u=ve^{1/v}$?

Comment: Well the homogenueous coordinates are $[a:b:c]$ on $c\neq 0$, the coordinates are $[a:b:c]\mapsto (a/c, b/c)$ and on $a\neq 0$ they're $[a:b:c]\mapsto (b/a, c/a)$ on the overlap, the change of coordinates is $(x,y)= (1/v, u/v)$.

Comment: Think about what the closure of $y=e^x$ would have to be in $\Bbb CP^2$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, I am not sure I understand your argument correctly, I can only think of the space of $\mathbb R^3=(x,y,z)$, and draw a curve of $y=e^x$ in the x-y plane, by stereographic projection, we pull back the curve to the sphere $\mathbb{RP}^2$, but I don't know if there is a equation describe the curve in $\mathbb{RP}^2$, and is it the closure in your description?

Comment: Where did real variables appear from? You had $(x,y)\in\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, yes, I know $(x,y)\in\Bbb C^2$ which is difficult to visualize, so I start from the $\mathbb R^2$ case and guess it will provide some clue what the $\mathbb C^2$ case look like, can you give directly what the 'closure' of $y=e^x$ is like?

Comment: This depends essentially on complex analysis. What does it tell you that $\infty$ is an essential singularity?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin，thanks, this explanation is heuristic for me, so you mean if we try to construct an analog of $y=e^x$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, it will cause an essential singularity which fails to be a subvariety of $\mathbb{CP}^2$?

Comment: Do you know Casorati-Weierstrass?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, actually I don't know Casorati-Weierstrass theorem before, but I have just google it and I think I can understand what is means.

Comment: It means that in a neighborhood of $z=\infty$ the image is dense. So what does that say about the closure of the graph in $\Bbb CP^2$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, it takes all the values of complex number infinite times, so the graph is the whole $\mathbb{CP}^2$ itself?

Comment: No, for finite $x$, there is a unique point $[1,x,e^x]$. For each finite $y$, there are countably many $x$ with $e^x=y$, true enough. But what I'm talking about is the closure — so what happens as $x\to\infty$, i.e., what points $[0,1,w]$ are in the closure of the graph? Answer: All of them. Is this set $\{[1,x,e^x]\}$ together with the entire line at $\infty$ an analytic subvariety of $\Bbb CP^2$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, did you have an image in your mind to help think about this phenomenen? For me it is a quite strange picture, for when $e^x$ is finite, it's a sequence of diferent $x$ disjoint with others, for $x\to \infty$, it's a whole line in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, the picture is rather strange, did not seem like an analytic subvariety.

Comment: Late to the party, but as for visualizing an essential singularity, the real graph $f(x) = e^{1/x^{2}}\cos(1/x)$ near $0$ should help illustrate the phenomenon Ted is describing. (The closure of the graph contains the $y$-axis.)